# Unable to resume activity since the database is closed

Tags: android, android-cursor

I am using rawQuery method to get the list of data as Cursor and using startManagingCursor() and stopManagingCursor() method. There is no problem for Activity1 and Activity2 but when I try to go to Activity2 from Activity3 it says `04-09 17:37:59.629: E/AndroidRuntime(6509): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.nepways.nlocate/com.nepways.nlocate.BusinessOrganizationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.nepways.nlocate/databases/nLocateDatabaseNew.db already closed`

Anyone have some help?

**UPDATE CODE**

```
    public class BusinessActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Business> businessList = new ArrayList<Business>();
    private BusinessListAdapter businessListAdapter;
    private ListView lvBusiness;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.business_list);

        businessList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("businessList");

        businessListAdapter = new BusinessListAdapter(this, businessList);

        lvBusiness = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBusiness);
        lvBusiness.setAdapter(businessListAdapter);
//      lvBusiness.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("Search").setIcon(R.drawable.ab_search).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
//      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Search")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Comment: where is your adapter? and exactly where error is coming?

Comment: I have solved it myself. I was missing stopManagingCursor(CursorObject); method call. I am not sure its the perfect solution, but it did solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please open your database, it is clearly mention that your database is close.

to open database call   `getReadableDatabase()`

Comment: Everything is working fine when going back to Activity1 from Activity2  , the problem is when from Activity3 back to Activity2. the codes are almost same. :(

Comment: i have added the code of Activity3, hope to get solution from you.

Comment: I was missing stopManagingCursor(CursorObj) call. I did find that when trying to copy my codes to show you so thanks a lot. :)